# Why are my alignments not working?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am trying to align all the = symbols in the photo below. However, all my attempts of using `\begin{align*}`with' `&...\\` to indicate alignment, produced nothing but errors. The best I could do was just add `&` without `align*` and, as you can see, most are aligned - but not all. When I continue adding `&` to other equations I get errors, again. [image]

How do I align the rest?
My code is messy, but here's what it looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\pagestyle{empty}
\date{}
\author{}
\title{Performing Row Operations to Solve Systems}
\maketitle
\vspace{-1.5cm} Recall a matrix for linear equations depends entirely on the coefficients of your variables. This allows you to create what is called an {\bfseries augmented matrix}. Consider the following example, and suppose $x_1=w, x_2=x, x_3=y, \text{and} \ x_4=z$. Remember the rows in the matrix must be placed in ascending order in terms of $x_n$ ($x_1, x_2, x_3...$), so you will need to rearrange the system and allow every gap to equal 0.
$$\begin{cases} 
x_2-3x_1+x_4&=2 \\
2x_1+4x_3&=5 \\
4x_2-x_4&=3 
\end{cases} 
\implies
\begin{cases}
-3w+x+\textcolor{red}{0y}+z&=2 \\
2w+\textcolor{red}{0x}+4y+\textcolor{red}{0z} &=5 \\
\textcolor{red}{0w}+4x+\textcolor{red}{0y}-z &=3 
\end{cases}
\implies
\newenvironment{amatrix}[1]{%
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|c@{}}
}{%
  \end{array}\right)
}
\begin{amatrix}{4}
-3 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\  
2 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 5 \\
0 & 4 & 0 & -1 & 3
 \end{amatrix}
$$
\\
$$
R_1=-\frac{1}{3}r_1 \implies
\newenvironment{amatrix}[1]{%
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|c@{}}
}{%
  \end{array}\right)
}
\begin{amatrix}{4}
1 & -\frac{1}{3} & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\
2 & 0 & 4 & 0 & -5 \\
0 & 4 & 0 & -1 & 3  
\end{amatrix}
R_2=-2r_1+r_2 \implies 
\begin{amatrix}{4}
1 & -\frac{1}{3} & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\
0 & \frac{2}{3} & 4 & \frac23 & \frac{19}{3} \\
0 & 4 & 0 & -1 & -\frac{5}{3}
\end{amatrix}
$$
\\
$$
R_2=\frac32r_2 \implies
\newenvironment{amatrix}[1]{%
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|c@{}}
}{%
  \end{array}\right)
}
\begin{amatrix}{4}
1 & -\frac13 & 0 & -\frac13 & -\frac23 \\
0 & 1 & 6 & 1 & \frac{19}{2} \\
0 & 4 & 0 & -1 & -\frac53
\end{amatrix}
R_3=-4r_2+r_3 \implies
\begin{amatrix}{4}
1 & -\frac13 & 0 & -\frac13 & -\frac23 \\ 
0 & 1 & 6 & 1 & \frac{19}{2} \\
0 & 0 & -24 & -5 & -35 
\end{amatrix}
$$
\\
$$
R_3=-\frac{1}{24}r_3 \implies
\newenvironment{amatrix}[1]{%
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|c@{}}
}{%
  \end{array}\right)
}
\begin{amatrix}{4}
1 & -\frac13 & 0 & -\frac13 & -\frac23 \\
0 & 1 & 6 & 1 & \frac{19}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{5}{24} & \frac{35}{24} 
\end{amatrix}
R_2=-6r_3+r_2
\implies
\begin{amatrix}{4}
1 & -\frac13 & 0 & -\frac13 & -\frac23 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac14 & \frac34 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{5}{24} & \frac{35}{24} 
\end{amatrix}
$$
\\
$$
R_1=\frac13r_2+r_1 \implies
\newenvironment{amatrix}[1]{%
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|c@{}}
}{%
  \end{array}\right)
}
\begin{amatrix}{4}
1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{5}{12} & -\frac{5}{12} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac14 & \frac34 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{5}{24} & \frac{35}{24} 
\end{amatrix}
\implies \begin{cases}
w-\frac{5}{12}z=-\frac{5}{12} \\
x-\frac14z=\frac34 \\
y+\frac{5}{24}z=\frac{35}{24}
\end{cases}
$$
\\
$$
\therefore \\
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\set\{\}
\{(\frac{5}{12}z-\frac{5}{12}, \frac{1}{4}z+\frac{3}{4}, -
\frac{5}{24}z+\frac{35}{24}, z)\}, \{z|-\infty<z<\infty\}$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I'm not able to test, so these are just a few suggestions.  First, blank lines aren't permitted in math.  Second, if you want to align several lines, you should take a look at the `align` environment from `amsmath` (`align*` if you don't want anything numbered).  And you really shouldn't be using `$$` -- `align` and similar environments are preferred for multi-line displays, and `equation` or `\[...\]` for one-line displays.  Finally, using `\\ ` between displays to get a blank output line will produce a warning.  Read the `amsmath` user guide.

Comment: In addition to what @barbarabeeton is saying, your equation is too wide. And you add `\newenvironment{amatrix}[1]{%
  \left(\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{c}|c@{}}
}{%
  \end{array}\right)
}` several times, so I would be surprised if your code runs through without complaints on your machine, on mine it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to suggest that you place only one row operation in each row. This will make it easier for your readers to figure out what's going on, and it will also assure that the material fits inside the width of the textblock.

Do place the definition of the `amatrix` environment in the preamble. That way, you don't have to repeat the `\newenvironment` statement over and over.

The following solution employs an outer `gather*` environment and an inner `aligned` environment. The `aligned` environments aligns not only the `=` symbols across the 7 rows, but also the `\implies` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,array}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\newenvironment{amatrix}[1]{%
   \left(\begin{array}{@{}*{#1}{r}|r@{}}}{%
   \end{array}\right)}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\set\lbrace\rbrace

\begin{document}
\section*{Performing Row Operations to Solve Systems}
\thispagestyle{empty}

Recall that a matrix for linear equations depends entirely on the 
coefficients of your variables. This allows you to create what is 
called an \emph{augmented matrix}. Consider the following example, 
and suppose $x_1=w$, $x_2=x$, $x_3=y$, and $x_4=z$. Remember that 
the rows in the matrix must be placed in ascending order in terms 
of~$x_n$ ($x_1, x_2, x_3, \dotsc$), so you will need to rearrange 
the system and allow every gap to equal~$0$.
\begingroup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25} % to give the arrays a more open "look"
\renewcommand\arraycolsep{4pt}   % default is 5pt
\medmuskip=3mu % default is 4mu
\begin{gather*}
\left\{ \begin{array}{@{}l@{{}={}}r@{}}
x_2-3x_1+x_4&2 \\
2x_1+4x_3&5 \\
4x_2-x_4&3
\end{array}\right.
\implies
\left\{ \begin{array}{@{}l@{{}={}}r@{}}
-3w+x+\textcolor{red}{0y}+z&2 \\
2w+\textcolor{red}{0x}+4y+\textcolor{red}{0z} &5 \\
\textcolor{red}{0w}+4x+\textcolor{red}{0y}-z &3
\end{array}\right.
\implies
\begin{amatrix}{4}
-3 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 5 \\
0 & 4 & 0 & -1 & 3
\end{amatrix} \\  
\begin{aligned}
R_1&=-\frac{1}{3}r_1 &&\implies
\begin{amatrix}{4}
1 & -\frac{1}{3} & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\
2 & 0 & 4 & 0 & -5 \\
0 & 4 & 0 & -1 & 3
\end{amatrix} \\
R_2&=-2r_1+r_2 &&\implies
\begin{amatrix}{4}
1 & -\frac{1}{3} & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\
0 & \frac{2}{3} & 4 & \frac23 & \frac{19}{3} \\
0 & 4 & 0 & -1 & -\frac{5}{3}
\end{amatrix} \\
R_2&=\frac32 r_2 &&\implies
\begin{amatrix}{4}
1 & -\frac13 & 0 & -\frac13 & -\frac23 \\
0 & 1 & 6 & 1 & \frac{19}{2} \\
0 & 4 & 0 & -1 & -\frac53
\end{amatrix}\\
R_3&=-4r_2+r_3 &&\implies
\begin{amatrix}{4}
1 & -\frac13 & 0 & -\frac13 & -\frac23 \\
0 & 1 & 6 & 1 & \frac{19}{2} \\
0 & 0 & -24 & -5 & -35
\end{amatrix} \\
R_3&=-\frac{1}{24}r_3 &&\implies
\begin{amatrix}{4}
1 & -\frac13 & 0 & -\frac13 & -\frac23 \\
0 & 1 & 6 & 1 & \frac{19}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{5}{24} & \frac{35}{24}
\end{amatrix}\\
R_2&=-6r_3+r_2&&\implies
\begin{amatrix}{4}
1 & -\frac13 & 0 & -\frac13 & -\frac23 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac14 & \frac34 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{5}{24} & \frac{35}{24}
\end{amatrix} \\
R_1&=\frac13r_2+r_1 &&\implies
\begin{amatrix}{4}
1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{5}{12} & -\frac{5}{12} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac14      & \frac34 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{5}{24}  & \frac{35}{24}
\end{amatrix}
\implies 
\left\{ \begin{array}{@{}l@{{}={}}r@{}}
w-\frac{5}{12}z&-\frac{5}{12} \\
x-\frac14z&\frac34 \\
y+\frac{5}{24}z&\frac{35}{24}
\end{array}\right.
\end{aligned}\\[2ex]
\therefore \quad
\set*{\bigl( \tfrac{5}{12}z-\tfrac{5}{12}, 
              \tfrac{1}{4}z +\tfrac{3}{4}, 
             -\tfrac{5}{24}z+\tfrac{35}{24}, 
              z
      \bigr) },\ 
\set{z\mid -\infty<z<\infty}
\end{gather*}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```